# How can I use Stroustrup's graphics libraries (Simple_window.h, Graph.h, ...) in Netbeans 7.3 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, ubuntu-12.10, fltk

everyone. I am learning Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming principle and practice using C++" book. I'm working with Netbeans 7.3 in Ubuntu 12.10. I want to build and run this simple graphics program in this book's chapter 12. The program is like this:

```
#include "Simple_window.h" // get access to our window library
#include "Graph.h" // get access to our graphics library facilities

int main()  
{    
    using namespace Graph_lib; // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib

    Point tl(100,100); // to become top left corner of window    
    Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas"); // make a simple window

    Polygon poly; // make a shape (a polygon)

    poly.add(Point(300,200)); // add a point    
    poly.add(Point(350,100)); // add another point    
    poly.add(Point(400,200)); // add a third point    
    poly.set_color(Color::red); // adjust properties of poly

    win.attach (poly); // connect poly to the window

    win.wait_for_button(); // give control to the display engine    
}
```

I can't build this program for 2 days. I added all graphics libraries in http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/ to my project. I also successfully installed FLTK-1.1.10 and configured it to Netbeans. All programs about FLTK run in Netbeans very well. But when it comes to build and run the program shown above, many errors occur. Errors are like this: "Undefined reference to ...". How can I solve this problem in Netbeans?

Errors occur like this:

g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_3 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/GUI.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Graph.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Simple_window.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Window.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L../../Downloads/fltk-1.1.10/lib -lfltk -lfltk_forms -lfltk_gl -lfltk_images -lfltk_jpeg
../../Downloads/fltk-1.1.10/lib/libfltk.a(Fl_get_system_colors.o): In function `getsyscolor(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, void (*)(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char))':
Fl_get_system_colors.cxx:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to`XGetDefault'
Fl_get_system_colors.cxx:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `XParseColor'
../../Downloads/fltk-1.1.10/lib/libfltk.a(Fl_get_system_colors.o): In function`fl_parse_color(char const*, unsigned char&, unsigned char&, unsigned char&)':
Fl_get_system_colors.cxx:(.text+0x2cd): undefined reference to `XParseColor' ... ...

Comment: Maybe you can show the command line that generates the error along with at least the first error that is encountered. A copy/paste of the error - not a description of it.

Comment: There are no errors in blue font

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to specify the X libraries to be linked in:

```
 -lXext -lX11
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now it works!!! It output small triange to screen. Thank you thank you! :)

Answer (score -2):

If you downloaded FLTK 1.3.3, the includes have different names than the previous versions. So at the page 1203 in Bjarne Stroustrup's book, the tutorial on how to install fltk isn't good anymore because they've changed so much. Here is a tutorial on how to install it for VS and how to set it up in a Win32 project. http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html
And on the fltk website, there are some tutorials there (not as well explained than Bjarne but it's alright).